# Unable to send POST request from the React frontend to Django Rest Framework using serializer?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to POST a request with data using fetch in React.js. How can I receive all the data sent in the body of the request options? I am attaching the serializer models for better understanding.

React Frontend(sending the post request with the data)

```
handleOnSubmit = (event)=>{
        const requestOptions = {
            method : "POST",
            headers : {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type":"application/json"},
            body : JSON.stringify({
                name:this.state.name,
                est:this.state.est,
                org:this.state.org
            }),
        };
        fetch("api/add-company", requestOptions).then((response)=>{return response.json()}).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data)
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank= False, null=False, unique=True)
    established = models.IntegerField()
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False, blank=False)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Company,Brand

class AddCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['name', 'established', 'origin']
        extra_kwargs = {'name':{'required':False},'established':{'required':False},'origin':{'required':False}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data send as body of POST request then you can use `request.POST.get()` method. In your case it would be:

```
name = json.loads(request.POST.get('name'))
est = json.loads(request.POST.get('est'))
org = json.loads(request.POST.get('org'))
```

Comment: Brother, I have tried using request.POST but failed to receive the data. As you can see when I print the serializer by print(serializer) statement, the output there is =AddCompanySerializer(data={'name': 'Nestle', 'est': '1866', 'org': 'Switzerland'}): name = CharField(max_length=30, required=False, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Company.objects.all())>]) established = IntegerField(required=False) origin = CharField(max_length=64, required=False)

Comment: But when I'm trying to access the data by serializer.data its returning only {'name': 'Nestle'} instead of the whole {'name': 'Nestle', 'est': '1866', 'org': 'Switzerland'}.

Comment: I have added an image of the form for better understanding in the main post.

Comment: please show the code of `AddCompanySerializer`

Comment: Thank you for responding brother. Added the models.py & serializers.py file at the end of the post now.

Comment: since you are sending json data, use `json.loads()`. I have edited the code in my answer above.

Comment: Used the json.loads() function. Still didn't work :-(

Comment: try removing `extra_kwargs` from `AddCompanySerializer`

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your serializer.

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    response = serializer.save()
    return Response(response.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: I removed the serializer.save() because it was unable to save and was raising an Integrity Error. Then I printed the serializer received from the frontend and the whole dict was present there: 
AddCompanySerializer(data={'name': 'Nestle', 'est': '1866', 'org': 'Switzerland'}): name = CharField(max_length=30, required=False, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Company.objects.all())>]) established = IntegerField(required=False) origin = CharField(max_length=64, required=False)
But when printed serializer.data it gave me an output of this :
{'name': 'Nestle'}

Comment: Your payload for requesting the POST was incorrect. Please correct the payload into the Stringify in JS code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. this fixed the problem. key names of the object inside the body has to be similar to the serializer's field names.